# prevent hover from triggering event twice

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I am trying to get an alert to work when a div is hovered over.

http://jsfiddle.net/4RgTS/248/

My current code is (for a div named 'testdiv')

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testdiv").hover(function() {
        alert('1');
    });
});
```

This works and shows the alert, but on the next mouse movement the alert is shown again even though I am not hovering over the div?

Thanks as always,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because if only one handler function is passed to `hover()` it is used for both the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. To get the behavior you want, change to use `mouseenter` only:

```
$("#testdiv").mouseenter(function () {
    alert('1');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4RgTS/250/)

Comment: When I hover again on it, it does the same.

Comment: That's correct. If you only want it to fire once, use `.one('mouseover', function() {...`

Comment: Yeah, okay I got the question wrong. Updated my answer too! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`$.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event for handling this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testdiv").one("mouseenter",
    function() {
      alert('1');
    });
});
```

```css
#testdiv {background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testdiv">Hover Me!!!</div>
```

---

Or, if I didn't get your question right, you just need to use the `mouseenter` event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testdiv").on("mouseenter",
    function() {
      alert('1');
    });
});
```

```css
#testdiv {background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testdiv">Hover Me!!!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you only want `.mouseenter()` event here:

```
$("#testdiv").mouseenter(function() {
      alert('1');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/egt9sLbp/)**